# How to eliminate spaces in a text file in text analysis?

Tags: java, frequency, analysis

I'm trying to make my program to display the frequency of the letters within a text file, at the moment it's displaying the frequency of every word within the text file. So for example if the words in the text file are "i am a man" it's outputting 4x letter frequencies for each word "i", "am", "a", "man".. where I need it to just analyze it all as one word so remove the spaces and see it as "iamaman".

//

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with having spaces in the text. In fact you're already taking care of ignoring the spaces when you check `Character.isLetter()` before adding to the count.

Mainly you just need to put your `for` and `while` loops that do the final counting outside of the main loop that iterates through the tokens.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class J_<countlettersfilereader> {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        // open the file
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the name of the text file? ");
        String fileName = console.nextLine();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        //initialize array with 26 elements
        int[] letterArray = new int[26]; 

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String next = input.next().toLowerCase();

            //run loop for each line incrementing per character
            for (int i = 0; i < next.length(); i++) {
                char characters = next.charAt(i);

                //ignore all characters which aren't alphabetic 
                if (Character.isLetter(characters)) {

                    //if character is uppercase then convert to lowercase
                    characters = Character.toLowerCase(characters);

                    //populate array 
                    int index = characters - 'a';
                    letterArray[index]++;
                }}
        }

        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < letterArray.length; i ++) {
            total += letterArray[i];
        }

        for (char characters = 'a'; characters <= 'z'; characters++) {
            int index = characters - 'a';
            //print out the analysis
            System.out.println("'" + characters + "' entered " + (((double)letterArray[index] / (double)total) * 100) 
                               + " percent");
        }
    }
}


$ cat abc.txt
a b c

$ java J_
What is the name of the text file? abc.txt
'a' entered 33.33333333333333 percent
'b' entered 33.33333333333333 percent
'c' entered 33.33333333333333 percent
'd' entered 0.0 percent
'e' entered 0.0 percent
'f' entered 0.0 percent
'g' entered 0.0 percent
'h' entered 0.0 percent
'i' entered 0.0 percent
'j' entered 0.0 percent
'k' entered 0.0 percent
'l' entered 0.0 percent
'm' entered 0.0 percent
'n' entered 0.0 percent
'o' entered 0.0 percent
'p' entered 0.0 percent
'q' entered 0.0 percent
'r' entered 0.0 percent
's' entered 0.0 percent
't' entered 0.0 percent
'u' entered 0.0 percent
'v' entered 0.0 percent
'w' entered 0.0 percent
'x' entered 0.0 percent
'y' entered 0.0 percent
'z' entered 0.0 percent
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understand, all you've to do is to leave the last for-loop outside the graph, so:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JCountlettersfilereader {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // open the file
    // Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    // System.out.print("What is the name of the text file? ");
    String fileName = "file.txt";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    // initialize array with 26 elements
    int[] letterArray = new int[26];
    int totalLetters = 0;

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String next = input.next().toLowerCase();

        // run loop for each line incrementing per character
        for (int i = 0; i < next.length(); i++) {
            char characters = next.charAt(i);

            // ignore all characters which aren't alphabetic
            if (Character.isLetter(characters)) {
                totalLetters++;
                // if character is uppercase then convert to lowercase
                characters = Character.toLowerCase(characters);

                // populate array
                int index = characters - 'a';
                letterArray[index]++;
            }
        }

        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < letterArray.length; i++) {
            total += letterArray[i];
        }
    }

        for (char characters = 'a'; characters <= 'z'; characters++) {
            int index = characters - 'a';
            // print out the analysis
            System.out
                    .println("'"
                            + characters
                            + "' entered "
                            + (((double) letterArray[index] / (double) totalLetters) * 100)
                            + " percent" +"("+letterArray[index] +" /"+totalLetters+")");
        }

}
}
```

It returns:

'a' entered 42.857142857142854 percent(3 /7)
...
'i' entered 14.285714285714285 percent(1 /7)
...
'm' entered 28.57142857142857 percent(2 /7)
'n' entered 14.285714285714285 percent(1 /7)

It is what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove spaces would be:

```
"i am a man".replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the code that prints out the results outside of the while loop. You only need to run this once, not once for every word in the file.

Also, you do not need to cast to lowercase on two different lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceAll("[\s]", "");`

This will remove all your white spaces (blank lines, tabs, spaces)

Comment: Take every line from your file one by one using for loop and inside the for loop put this code to remove white spaces

Answer (score 0):

You could set a delimiter as `\\w` meaning that it will not take spaces

Set

```
input.setDelimeter("\\w");
```

Outside the while loop